# My own DNS server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, domain

sorry for bad english
I have domain name (without IP assign) like blahblah.com, and I have linux VPS with Static IP like 123.123.123.123.
How Can I assign IP to my domain name? Is it possible I run my own DNS server or I use any free DNS server?

Comment: Typically the domain registrar that you used to purchase the domain offers DNS services as well.  Running your own is doable, but more complex; you may want to stick to the simpler option unless you're confident in your ability to run it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to contact your registrar.  This is where you purchased/registered your domain.

There, you will need to configure the DNS server or servers configured for you domain blahblah.com.  Some registrars will offer a service to do this.  If they offer this service, my advice is to use it as this will be simpler.  All you will need to do is then give a hostname or wildcard configuration pointing to 123.123.123.123.

The other alternative is to use the registrar to configure your nameserver(s) for your domain to point to your VPS.  This is not recommended for a few reasons.  First, it is more complicated to setup.  Second, you should really have multiple nameservers for a domain for redundancy.  Some domains will require this.  Folks with a single VPS have gone so far as to configure multiple IPs on their VPS host to satisfy the multiple hosts requirement.  This is obviously working around the problem without solving it.

Answer (score 1):

If you purchased the domain from GoDaddy or a site like that, they'll host your DNS for you. All you have to do is point the DNS records for the resources you plan on hosting to the IP of your server.

For example, if you're hosting a website on your server, you're going to want to change the IP in the 'www' record to reflect the IP of your server.

If you're hosting mail, you're going to want to change the 'mail' entry to your IP (if you're hosting webmail) and modify the MX records to point to your server as well.

This is [GoDaddy's DNS help section](http://help.godaddy.com/article/680?locale=en), but the principles will apply no matter who you purchased the domain from.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set some of this up wherever you registered your domain at.

- Set your nameservers for the domain to whoever is hosting your VPS

  or
- If your registrar provides DNS capabilities then add your server as a Host record (A)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it in the same place where you registered your domain. 
Check our various DNS record types:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types

Based on what you are trying to achieve you can have your own dns server or usually your domain registrar provides you with the default name servers.